# How can I query a nested document and return attributes from it?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a Product collection and every document looks something like this:

```
"_id" : ObjectId("574393c59afcfdd3763d91b1"),
    "name" : "dummy product name",
    "price" : 200,

    "category" : ObjectId("574393c59afcfdd3763d91ad"),
    "images" : [ ],
    "ratings" : [
            2
    ],
    "reviews" : [ ],
    "purchase_count" : 0,
    "tags" : [
            ObjectId("574393c59afcfdd3763d91a9"),
            ObjectId("574393c59afcfdd3763d91ab")
    ]
```

Where category and tags are references to their respective collections and they each have a name attribute. Here are all 3 schemas:

```
   var ProductSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
   name : {type: String, required: true},
   price : { type: Number,required: true },
   tags : [{ type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Tag' }],
   purchase_count : {type: Number, default: 0},
   reviews : [ReviewSchema],
   ratings : [{type: Number, min: 0, max: 10}],
   category : {type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'ProductCategory'},
   images : [{type: String}]
});

    var ProductCategorySchema = new mongoose.Schema({
   name : { type: String, required: true, unique: true, dropDups: true }});

    var TagSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
   name : { type: String, required: true, unique: true, dropDups: true, lowercase: true }
});
```

I'm trying to query the product collection and return data of each product like this:

```
app.models.Product.find({}, function(err, products){
  if (err) throw err;
  res.json(products);
}).populate('category').populate('tags').exec();
```

The only the difference is that I want the actual name of the category instead of a document representing the collection with it's ID. I also want the same for the tags , I just want a simple array of strings which represent the tag names. How can I do this in the query?

I tried implicitly defining what I wanted to select by using a select() after the second populate() and writing 'category.name tags.name (and then all the other attributes)' but that didn't work.

This is what the result of the query looks like:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To select specific field you would

```
app.models.Product.find({}, function(err, products){
  if (err) throw err;
  res.json(products);
}).populate('category', 'fieldname1 fieldname2').populate('tags', 'fieldname1 fieldname2').exec();
```

http://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html

However i dont see in your schema definition any reference to anything.

Also if you have / need any kind of relation (which is what you seem to need) dont use mongo.

Actually dont use mongo ever unless you absolutely must - try to stay a way from mongo.

**update**

Something like that.

```
 var res = app.models.Product.find({}, function(err, products){
  if (err) throw err;
    res.json(products);
 }).populate('category', 'fieldname1 fieldname2').populate('tags', 'fieldname1 fieldname2').exec();

res.category = categoty.fieldname;
res.tags = res.tags.map(function(tag){

  return tag.fieldname
})
```

Another option might be - to add getter - not sure if this will work because populate might happened after so ..

but :

```
ProductSchema.virtual('categoryString').get(function () {
  return this.category.fieldname
});

ProductSchema.virtual('tagsArr').get(function () {
  return this.tags.map(function(tag){
     if(tag && tag.name) {
         return tag.fieldname;
     }
     return '';
  });
});
```

Comment: I tried that too. It still returns the document object but it only keeps the fields you specify.

Comment: And you want it do be something like user.category = ['cat1',  'cat2'] ?

Comment: The category is only a single string, but the tags should be like that, yes.

Comment: you will have to do it your self, something like the above. check my update

Comment: Your first update is not working. "Cannot read property 'name' of undefined".

Comment: You need to adapt it to your own properties ofc. I dont know what your real object look like after populate. post it somewhere.

Comment: I did. 'name' is what the property is called.

Comment: check if it even fetched anything from the DB. because my code doesnt do anything to a property named 'name'

Comment: Show how your object looks after you pull if off the DB

Comment: See my small change tell me what happened, because with the object you described it should work perfectly so i must assume something is missing

Comment: I posted the code I wrote that worked as an answer. Giving you best answer for your idea and effort. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

This is how I got it to work. Credit goes to Neta Meta for giving me the idea of using pure JS.

```
app.models.Product.find({})
.populate('category' , 'name')
.populate('tags', 'name').populate('seller', 'name').exec(function(err, products){

  if (err) throw err;

  products = products.map(function(a){

    var productToSend = {};
    productToSend.name = a.name;
    productToSend.price = a.price;
    productToSend.description = a.description;

    if(a.seller != undefined){
      productToSend.seller = a.seller.name;
    }

    if(a.tags != undefined){
      productToSend.tags = a.tags.map(function(b){
        return b.name;
      });
    }
    productToSend.purchase_count = a.purchase_count;
    productToSend.reviews = a.reviews;
    productToSend.ratings = a.ratings;

    if(a.category != undefined){
      productToSend.category = a.category.name;
    }

    productToSend.images = a.images;

    return productToSend;

  })
  res.json(products);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why you send response before populate query. Using [lodash](https://lodash.com/docs) package to modified your products before response.

```
var _ = require('lodash');

app.models.Product.find({}).populate('category tags').exec(function(err, products){    
    if (err) throw err;
    var modified = _.map(products, function (product) {
        product.tags = _.map(product.tags, function (tag) { return _.pick(tag, ['name']) });
        product.category = _.pick(product.category, ['name']);
        return product;
    });    
    res.json(modified);
});
```

Comment: Same thing. Still returns both category and tags as documents.

Comment: yes, _id filed always present. but name of tags and category are present too?

Comment: Yes but they're in the object so I don't know how to access them.

Comment: try console.log(JSON.stringify(products));

Comment: What good would that do? Do you just want to see what 'res' looks like? If so, take a look at my updated post.

Comment: using lodash then modify your products as you want before you response it to client

Comment: lodash is absolutely redundant here.

Comment: @NetaMeta yes, just a way to modified object